# Find Litigation involving a specific Company in the UK

Tags: united-kingdom

I am researching cases of litigation against company Interactive Brokers in the UK.

Is there a way to conveniently browse via internet existing court cases using such filters?

Comment: What's the case name i can give it a try

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks  I am rather looking for any cases related to that firm. Use case: I want to open a trading account with Interactive Brokers, and I want to know whether opening it under a limited company (rather than on my own name) would help insulate my personal finance in case of extreme losses that would be larger than the account size. Hence I wanted to consult UK litigation records to see if there was a precedent to such case. (limited company bankruptcy while trading with Interactive Brokers)

Comment: I can tell you as a lawyer that opening an account as a limited liability company would indeed insulate your losses to whatever your company owns

Comment: I'm not sure how you would lose more money than you put into the account... are you wanting to trade on margin or with borrowed funds? Any financial advisor would highly recommend against doing something like that unless you have the liquidity to cover the loss. Just having a LLC doesn't fully insulate you in certain situations, so I would highly recommend sitting down with an attorney specialized in LLC's to discuss your specific concerns and plan. I don't think reading specific cases for that company will help, usually they would pass the debt on to a collector which would sue you.

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks Thanks a lot for your reply! This would be my understanding as well since limited companies exists for that express purpose. However I would like to make sure that in the specific case that I mentioned, the opposite party cannot invoke  moral hazard or negligent mismanagement to hold me, as the director, personally responsible for the repayment. Hence seeing some jurisprudence on that topic would help me strengthen my confidence on the typical course of such issue.

Comment: @RonBeyer I see, interesting comment regarding the debt collector. If you know some internet links where I could see reports of examples of that, would be helpful. Obviously yes discussing it with an attorney is better than here, but I was hoping that getting some early internet pointers could be interesting. And in any case, understanding how to browse UK cases looking for jurisprudence (if such thing is possible) would be interesting for me.

Comment: @Vincent Negligent mismanagement would only allow a shareholder in your company to sue you for causing the company to go bankrupt. If you maintain 100% percent ownership of your company this would not be an issue. There may be accusations of fraud if your purpose was not to make money but to cause losses for Interactive Brokers, but as long as you can show that the business was genuinely created to make profits, you will be fine

Comment: @ShazamoMorebucks Thanks a lot